# Calculate values for the array by the gradient

Tags: arrays, swift, gradient

I have a float array with two dimensions which must have normalized [0,1] values and which represents a "heat map" in my case. Value of each cell depends from how far it is located from the center of the map, only one axis (vertical or y) matters (which pretty much looks like a gradient which goes up/down from the center). Central cells must have the max value (1) and cells on the borders must have minimum value (0). So what I need is a function which can calculate a value for each cell.
Here is an example of how values in the array may look like (red color represents maximum value and blue represents minimum value, colors may not follow the gradient, so don't judge it):

[image]

And here is the code which I use for initializing the array, I know that required function must lay somewhere there:

```
func createBandsForTwoDArray() -> [[Float]] {
    let columns = 100
    let rows = 100
    var twoDArray = Array(repeating: Array(repeating: Float(0), count: columns), count: rows)
    for y in 0..<rows {
        for x in 0..<columns {
            // How to calculate cell value?
            let n = magicValueCalculation(x, y)
            twoDArray[y][x] = Float(n)
        }
    }
    return twoDArray
}
```

Comment: The question is lacking detail, and is rather broad ("help me figure this out"). Detailed questions that ask something narrow and specific get better results. Also, any images relevant to the question are best inlined in the question. I didn't downvote, but that is why I often see questions downvoted.

Comment: Not sure why the first part of the question *"how to add a gradient value into each coordinate"* is related to *"how would I go about adding these bands"* - can you elaborate on the motivation for doing so? Also, pretty sure this band structure is in no way a physically realistic temperature distribution.

Comment: If you need help with some related to your question, you need to put that relevant code into your question (as text, not a picture of code). And clearly indicate what help you need with the code.

Comment: First you need to define "band" in the context of your program. If you just have a grid, then it would seem that a row is a band. So make each row have the same value across its entirety.

Comment: Your desired output is currently a picture, but your code outputs an array - How are those things linked? How do the colours correspond to the values? How do you determine the desired colours for the bands? How wide are the bands? It might be better to just forget about the picture for now and simplify this to just working with the floats where you have some input and you have some desired output array, and then maybe write down what exactly you want your loop to do at each step, and then try to turn that into a loop.

Comment: No idea how else to ask the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand you need a function which will return normilized value which depends on how far float cell is located relative to the map center(as farest as smaller value gets; only one axis matters)

The general idea is:

1. devide cell position by map size
2. subtract half (0.5) from that value
3. get value by subtration multiplied twice previous absolute value from one

Code:

```
func createBandsForTwoDArray(columns: Int, rows: Int) -> [[Float]] {
    var twoDArray = Array(repeating: Array(repeating: Float(0), count: columns), count: rows)
    for y in 0..<rows {
        let h = getHeat(pos: Float(y), len: Float(rows)) // Heat needs calculation only once per row
        for x in 0..<columns {
            twoDArray[y][x] = h
        }
    }
    return twoDArray
}

func getHeat(pos: Float, len: Float) -> Float {
    var heat = pos/len-0.5
    heat = 1-abs(heat)*2
    return heat
}
```

Where pos is y position of the cell and len is map height. Also, since members of the same row will have same values, you can speed up your method by finding value for each row only once. And also you can pow the result if you requier non liniar function.

Comment: This is a well formed answer, but the OP is looking for an answer using Swift.  Please translate your C# code into Swift.